# I am trying to write a script where a horizontal line will automatically be plotted based on MACD

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Hi I am trying to write a script where a horizontal line will automatically be plotted and replotted every-time a new green high on MACD comes, as well as a red low on MACD. I am wanting the horizontal line to be at the top of the highest candle inside the green on MACD and be able to re-plot if a new one gets made, and vise versa for the low and red. Any Ideas?[The arrows are pointing where i want the horizontal lines to be plotted, but i want them to be able to reprint based on newer highs and newer lows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1qe5.jpg)

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far so we can help.

Comment: @vitruvius I haven’t tried really anything. I have absolutely no idea where to even start..